# Batch normalization of images of range [0 inf]

Tags: deep-learning, autoencoder, batch-normalization

I'm working on an autoencoder network, outputting medical images. The image pixels values are quantitative and of range [0 inf]. My network input is also quantitative of range [0 inf]. Basically, if the input pixel values are increased by a factor 10, so should the output pixel values.

Most work I've seen use images that are scaled to [0 255]. Since I want to keep the actual scaling and quantitative information of my output, my question is this: Is it appropriate to use batch normalization layers in your autoencoder? Or will all scaling be lost, and only relative pixel information remain?

I appreciate any thoughts! :)